# SQL Table Joins - Combining Related Data from Two Rows into One Row

Tags: sql, mysql

Table 1

```
Id
bedroom_color_id
bathroom_color_id
Table two
```

Table 2

```
Id
color_id
red_value
blue_value
yellow_value
```

I am currently working on joining two SQL tables: `table_one` and `table_two`. The structure of these tables is as shown above.

The query I am currently using is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table_two AS t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

With the above query, I receive two separate rows as a result. The first row contains values from `table_two` that correspond to `bedroom_color_id` from `table_one`, while the second row contains values from `table_two` that correspond to `bathroom_color_id` from `table_one`.

My goal is to combine the data from these two rows into a single row in the result set. Is there a way to do this without directly joining `table_two` using either `bedroom_color_id` or `bathroom_color_id`?

Comment: I think you need to use an `inner join` to accomplish this. Could you provide some sample data from both tables? You can use https://www.db-fiddle.com/ to share a demo.

Comment: Sample data and expected results please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't want to join on `bed_colour` or `bath_color`. You can do both in one query, and extract the result you're looking for.

```
    create table tableOne (
      id int auto_increment primary key,
      bath_colour int not null,
      bed_colour int not null
      );
      create table tableTwo (
        id int auto_increment primary key,
        colourId int,
        red int,
        blue int,
        green int
        );
        
        insert tableTwo (colourId, red, green, blue) values (1,5,5,5),(2,10,10,10),(3,25,65,34);
        insert tableOne (bath_colour, bed_colour) values (1,3)
        

---

**Query #1**

    select * from tableTwo;

| id  | colourId | red | blue | green |
| --- | -------- | --- | ---- | ----- |
| 1   | 1        | 5   | 5    | 5     |
| 2   | 2        | 10  | 10   | 10    |
| 3   | 3        | 25  | 34   | 65    |

---
**Query #2**

    select * from tableOne;

| id  | bath_colour | bed_colour |
| --- | ----------- | ---------- |
| 1   | 1           | 3          |

---
**Query #3**

    select t1.id, bed.red as bedRed, bath.red as bathRed from tableOne as t1
    join tableTwo as bed on (t1.bed_Colour = bed.colourId)
    join tableTwo as bath on  (t1.bath_Colour = bath.colourId);

| id  | bedRed | bathRed |
| --- | ------ | ------- |
| 1   | 25     | 5       |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)